# How do I package an unchanged C extension as part of my new Python package?

Tags: python, packaging, distutils

I've released a new version of a Python package to pypi without changing the C extension. Since I have only changed the Python code, not the C code, how do I package the shared libraries I have compiled for several platforms without having to recompile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example for a library called 'somelib' with compiled libraries in two subdirectories, lib-i386 and lib-amd64:

MANIFEST.in contains the following:

```
include __init__.py
include setup.py
include somelib/*
include somelib/lib-i386/*
include somelib/lib-amd64/*
```

setup.py contains (I've omitted lines unessential to the versioning issue):

```
# Determine machine arhitecture
arch = os.uname()[4]
libname = "lib-%s" % (arch,)
lib_files = glob.glob('./somelib/' + libname + '/*')
data_files = [('somelib', 
              lib_files + ['__init__.py', 'somelib/README.TXT']),]

setup(
   ... 
   data_files=data_files
)
```

All the library objects are inside the package, but only the ones specific to 'arch' are installed.

HTH.